# How to Change Sharepoint Domain Name

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to know how to change the name of my SharePoint intranet domain name from how do i change my SharePoint domain name from "oldsite.sharepoint.com" to "newsite.sharepoint.com"

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately,** it isn't possible to change the SharePoint Online domain name  from "`oldsite.sharepoint.com`" to "`newsite.sharepoint.com`" for your organization in Office 365!

To use the domain name `newsite.sharepoint.com` , you would need to purchase a new Office 365 subscription and move all email, files, and any other data you want to keep to the new subscription.

For more details, Check, [Change your SharePoint domain name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-your-sharepoint-domain-name)